# Show that $B(t): \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2} := (t^{3}, |t^{3}|)$ is not an example of a $1-$manifold in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, manifolds

Munkres defines a $k$-manifold in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ as follows:

[image]

As an example (according to Munkres):

$$B(t): \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2} := (t^{3}, |t^{3}|)$$

is not an instance of a $1-$manifold in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, since although $B(t)$ has a continuous inverse and is $C^{2}$, the rank of $DB(t)$ at $t = 0$ is not $1$.

I understand everything except how $B(t)$ is $C^{2}$ however:

If $U'$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}$ containing $0$, then $$\frac{\partial B_{2}}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial|t^{3}|}{\partial t} $$

does not exist at $t = 0$. If the first partial does not exist, how can the function even be considered of class $C^{2}$?

Comment: Are you sure that $d|t^3|/dt$ does not exist at $t = 0$?

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Derivative_of_Absolute_Value_Function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first derivative of $\lvert t^3\rvert$ exists at $t=0$; it is $0$, since the left-hand and right-hand limits of the Newton quotient are both $0$, because

$$
\frac{\lvert t^3\rvert-0}{t-0}=\text{sgn}(t)t^2\to 0
$$

The second derivative also exists and is $0$ at $t=0$. It is only the third derivative that fails to exist, making this a function of class $C^2$.

Note for comparison that $\lvert t\rvert$ is a function that doesn't have a first derivative.

Answer (score 0):

Because the first two derivatives of $t^3$ are zero at $t-0$, $|t^3|$ is in fact twice differentiable at $t=0$. (It is not thrice differentiable.)